# Listbox removing Item

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm trying to use something like `listId.Items.Remove(listId.SelectedItem[x]);` after each item has been processed. Obviously that doesn't work any suggestions:

```
int listCellCounter = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < listId.Items.Count; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(txtWebUpdate.Text + listId.Items[x].ToString() + "&ire=1", listCell.Items[listCellCounter].ToString());
    listId.SelectedIndex = x;
    listCell.SelectedIndex = listCellCounter;
    lblID.Text = listId.Items[x].ToString();

    if (listCellCounter == listCell.Items.Count - 1)
    {
        listCellCounter = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        listCellCounter += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is missing context.

Comment: Provide more information. Do you use ObservableCollection ?

Comment: When you say "Obviously this doesn't work"....what do you mean, doesn't work? What isn't working for you?

Comment: how about this, forget about listId.Items.Remove(listId.SelectedItem[x]); by reading my code (its only 15lines) if you wanted to remove an item after each process/loop what would you type in.

Comment: So, you want to remove each item one by one at the end of the loop?

Comment: If you are deleting from a collection then I think you have to start from the last item and work backwards otherwise you will soon get an index out of range error

Comment: I didn't test it in any way but isn't it suppose to DoEvents somewhere or other repainting method in order to observe said removal? Otherwise it will remove at the end of each loop and show you just the end result.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski Yes sir. I just need help with what needs to be written to do that.

Comment: @acctman: Why not just remove all of the items at once after the loop ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of processing is not critical then start at the last item. For example:

```
for (int x = listId.Items.Count-1; x > 0; x--) {}
```

Comment: so change the processing order and then I can use something like listId.Items.Remove(listId.SelectedItem); to remove selected items?

Comment: Yes. You process from the end of a collection. As you remove each one your next iteration will look at the last one in the list and you can process that. If you go your way you will hit an index out of range error

Comment: That could get real expensive if the list lookup is O(N).  But that's actually really neat if it's O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would suggest processing the selected items in a list like this if you're removing them as they are processed:

```
for(int x = listId.SelectedIndex; x >= 0; x = listId.SelectedIndex)
{
   // Do your processing here
   listId.Items.RemoveAt(x);
   listId.Update();
}
```

But it looks like you're processing every item in the list.  If that's the case, maybe this is appropriate:

```
while (listId.Items.Count > 0)
{
   listId.SelectedIndex = 0;
   listId.Update();
   // Do your processing here
   listId.Items.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Comment: I copied it from a functioning test application... what do you think I need to reread?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is a mark and sweep algorithm.  Build a list of objects to delete in your for loop (instead of deleting them) and then delete all the items in that list after you have calculated which objects need to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to display the removal of each item to the user, just empty the `ListBox` when the loop is complete:

```
} //end loop

listId.Clear();
```